# the same Animating my character's leg brings part of the other foot with it

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, rigify

I'm making a rabbit in blender and I parented my front and back foot and when i'm trying to animate, both my front foot and my back foot will move together. I want to separate the foots from moving together. Please help.

Comment: Can you add your blend file to the question so we can look at it?  It sounds like you have both feet in the vertex group for the front foot, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: i don't know how to add a blend file

Comment: Grab the URL of the question
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/
Select the blend file
Add the url of the question
Grab the url that results
Go back to the question and edit it
Add the new url to the bottom of the post

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=GEwDqyxG" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/GEwDqyxG/)

Comment: You're supposed to edit your post and add that, rather than put it in a comment. But the comment works and I'll take a look at your file later today.